# How do i pass a bearer authorization token with ApiSauce

Tags: javascript, api, axios, apisauce

Please help check if the method i used to pass the bearer authorization token, because its not working, Maybe im missing something please

```
apiClient.addAsyncRequestTransform(async (request) => {
  const authToken = await authStorage.getToken();
  if (!authToken) return;
  request.headers["Authorization"] = "access " + authToken;
});
```

[image: Postman Screenshot]

[image: React Native Debugger]

Answer (score 3):

A bearer token normally starts with the phrase `bearer`. So, replace the word `access` with `bearer` and try again:

```
apiClient.addAsyncRequestTransform(request => async () => {
  const authToken = await authStorage.getToken();
  if (!authToken) return;
  request.headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + authToken;
});
```

Comment: Still the same issue... what do you think please

Comment: Can you mention the API Documentation you use?

Comment: API Sauce, i tested it with Postman and it works when I put the token in the bearer option under authorization tab... But in my app, while inspecting the api with React native debugger, it keeps says 401 unauthorized

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the Postman request?

Comment: Please check, just added it

Comment: Tried that too. Still the same.

Comment: Hey, You're right, I just noticed something. .. although its still not working, but its passing the Bearer + Token to the backend as I inspected the network.  I think else might be the problem. I'm just tired

Comment: Okay. Let's see

Comment: Thanks. I have updated the question, please check

Answer (score 0):

Here is my Complete Code:

```
import apisauce from 'apisauce';
import { Constants } from '../utils/Constants';
import LocalStorage from '../Service/LocalStorage'
let local = new LocalStorage()

export const createBackendServer = (baseURL = Constants.BASE_URL) =>
{
 const api = apisauce.create({
 baseURL,
 timeout: 30 * 1000,
  });

 api.setHeaders({
  Accept: 'application/json',
 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  })

 api.addAsyncRequestTransform(request => async () => {
  await local.getSession((res) => {
   if (res.token) {
request.headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + res.token;
 }
 })
});

 const signUpUser = (body) => api.post('/signup', body);
 const signInWithEmailPassword = (body) => api.post('/login', body);
  const signOut = () => api.get('/logout');

  return {
 signUpUser,
 signInWithEmailPassword,
 signOut
};
};
```